# How to debug netlink messages

Tags: android, linux, kernel

I am using netlink to send a message(sendmsg) from one app to vold manager in android. sendmsg does not return any error but it seems it is not able to perform the expected task. I am trying to log stuff from vold but I dont see any logs. (I am using SLOGE and printf to log stuff). I try to see log using logcat but dont see anything. I want to know how to debug sendmsg on netlink. What could be the best way to see where I am going wrong.

Thanks

Comment: Found the answer. I m stupid, should have struck before. vold has a netlinkhandler. Started putting prints and found the issue.